# Playout system for fluid Web App

Tags: graphics, google-chrome, webapps

For my company I'm programming the GUI for an interactive table using Web Technologies and react.js. It's for a showroom of a rather big client and it's been a bit of a hustle to convince my colleagues and get their trust to use Web Technologies and react to do this job. I believe it suits perfectly and it's also a personal motivation to promote Web Tech for such tasks, specifically JS and node.

Now the GUI will have quite some animation going on (not that I like it but the client does and so wants it) and the question is, what machine to use for a fluid rendering performance. It's all CSS animations/transitions triggered by react state changes.

We will use an Ubuntu system and Chrome and are now evaluating what specs the machine should have to ensure a fluid, performant rendering of the app.

I was thinking of a Chromebox but not sure if that'd be strong enough.

Could a Chromebox do? Could a strong graphics card/chip help for hardware accelerated browser rendering?